# How to change Text color of push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, colors, push-notification, notifications

In this image i want to change the color of the push notification TEXT from white to black or any other color.

[image: In this image i want to change the color of the push notification TEXT from white to black or any other color.]

need help with coding part or any documentation.

[I want this type of solution in which text color is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Ncs.png)

Comment: I don't see any color in your second screenshot. It's just  dark vs light theme... You shouldn't be able to add colors, since it's just simple text with no attributes I think...

Comment: yes you are right it is dark vs light theme I used it for an example ,But is it possible to change text color?

Comment: I don't think so. You jus have the App Name (can't be changed), Date, "Title" in bold image and text. There is afterwards customization possible, but only when user long press on it, on use an action button (with a swipe etc.)

Comment: You cannot change the summary format. You can implement a notification extension to customise the expanded appearance.